# Where is "make" after installing Xcode?

Tags: xcode, makefile

When I try to run `make` form a terminal it says:

```
-bash: make: command not found
```

I already have Xcode installed on my Mac, what could be the problem?

(It's OSX 10.8.5 and Xcode 5.1.1.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to install the command line tools for XCode.

To do that open Xcode go to `Xcode` -> `Preferences` -> `Downloads` and add the component named Command Line Tools.

This will place all relevant tools to your `Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin` folder.